# How to get geo notification using "While Using the App" location service

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, geofencing

I am using geofence services in one of my applications.

When I have *"Always"* location permission, I get region entry/exit notifications.

If I have only  *"While in use"*  location permission then I don't get region entry/exit notifications.

This is in alignment with Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services#see-also)

However, when I give the Google Maps application *"While in use"* location permissions, it is getting region notifications.

How can my app get region notifications with only *"While in use"* permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: You need "Always" permission for region monitoring, as per the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing in the Google Maps application to trigger a region entry/exit notification in that app?

Comment: Just I have set Allow location service as "While in use" and add my waypoints and destination in to the Google Map. It is giving me notification every waypoint.

Comment: Apple developer document says, If you are using "Region Monitoring" then you must have set Allow location service as "Always". then my question is How Google Map app work "Region Monitoring" using "While in use". Is there other way to achieve this things.

Comment: When Google Maps is providing directions, it is considered by iOS to be "in use" even though it is in the background; You will notice the blue bar "Google Maps is using your location".  It doesn't need region monitoring; it will be receiving a continuous stream of location updates in order to provide directions.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have understand your point. Thank you.